# Stack a numeric data frame and change the column names in a single instruction

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a purely numeric data frame, whose columns I want to stack (concatenate) together. `stack` does a good job:

```
foo <- matrix(rnorm(100),20,5)
foo <- data.frame(foo)
bar <- stack(foo)
```

However, I don't like the default column names given by `stack`, i.e., `values` and `id`. Of course, I can change them with

```
colnames(bar) <- c("x","y")
```

but I was wondering if there was any function which would allow me to define the column names of the resulting (stacked) data frame.

Comment: why the edits? It's perfectly fine R code to use `=` instead than `<-`. I don't see why I should conform to your coding style.

Comment: `\`colnames<-\`(stack(foo), c('x','y'))`

Comment: you can use whatever style you like. but when sharing code and/or asking for help, I would highly encourage you at least to use your spacebar. youdonttypeoutsentenceslikethisdoyou?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `melt` function in the `reshape2` library:

```
library(reshape2)
bar <- melt(foo, value.name = "x", variable.name = "y")
```

P.S:

- Note that the order of the columns is opposite to the one resulting from the call to the stack function
- You can use the `melt` function from the `data.table` package in exact the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `gather` function from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

gather(foo, y, x)
```